# Lock future file

Tags: java, file, locking, file-locking

So I have a Samba file server on which my Java app needs to write some files. The thing is that there is also another php application (if a php script is even considered an application) that is aggressively pulling the same directory for new files.

Sometimes, the php script is pulling the file before my Java app is done writing it completely to the disk. Here is a little bit of ascii art to help visualize what I currently have (but doesn't work):

**Samba share**

`/foo` (my java app drops file here)

`/bar` (the directory that the php is pulling)

What I'm currently doing is when the file meets some criterias, it's being moved to `/bar` and then picked up by the php for more processing. I've tried different thing such has setting the file non writable and non readable before calling `renameTo`.

I've looked a little bit at `FileLock`s but it doesn't seem to be able to lock future files. So I am wondering what kind of possiblities I have here? What could I use to lock the file from being picked up before it's fully written without touching the php (because, well, it's php and I don't really have the right to modify it right now).

Thanks

**Edit 1**

I've got some insight on what the php script is really doing if it can help in any way.

It's reading the directory file in loop (using [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) without sleeping).

As soon as it finds a filename other than "." and "..", it calls [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and that's where it fails because the file is not completely written to disk (or not even there since the Java code might not even had time to write it between the `readdir` and `file_get_contents`.

**Edit 2**

This Java application is replacing an old php script. When they implemented it, they had the same problem I'm having right now. They solved it by writing the new file in `/bar/tmp`(with `file_put_contents`) and then use [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to move it to bar (it looks like rename is supposed to be atomic). And it's been working fine so far. I can't and won't believe that Java can't do something better than what php does...

Comment: Are /foo and /bar on the same filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the fact read locks are shared (multiple process can apply read locks to the same file and read it together).

One approach you can do is to create a separate temporary lock file (eg: `/bar/file1.lock`) while `/bar/file1` hasn't finished copying. Delete the lock file as soon as the file copying is finished.

Then alter the php code to ensure the file isn't being locked before it reads.

Comment: I had the same thought, but the question unfortunately states that modifying the PHP is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html), but keep in mind the disclaimer in the javadoc for that method:

> Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing
>   the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore
>   unspecified. The native file-locking facilities of some systems are
>   merely advisory, meaning that programs must cooperatively observe a
>   known locking protocol in order to guarantee data integrity.

You also mentioned you are using [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29), which also has some caveats (mentioned in the javadoc):

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed

Instead of `File.renameTo`, Try [Files.move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) with the `ATOMIC_MOVE` option.  You'll have to catch [AtomicMoveNotSupportedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AtomicMoveNotSupportedException.html) and possibly fall back to some alternative workaround in case an atomic move is not possible.

You could create a hardlink with [`Files.createLink(Paths.get('/foo/myFile'), 'Paths.get('/bar/myFile'))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createLink%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29) then delete the original directory entry (in this example, `/foo/myFile`.

Failing that, a simple workaround that doesn't require modification to the PHP is to use a shell command or system call to move the file from /foo to /bar.  You could, for example, use `ProcessBuilder` to call `mv`, or perhaps call `ln` to create a symlink or hardlink in /bar.  You might still have the same problem with `mv` if /foo and /bar are on different filesystems.

If you have root privileges on the server, you could also try implementing mandatory file locking.  I found an [example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-file-locking-types/) in C, but you could call the C program from Java or adapt the example to Java using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) (or JNI if you want to punish yourself).

Comment: The ATOMIC_MOVE option doesn't do any different. File is still being picked up before completely wrote to disk. I'm getting weird exceptions with ProcessBuilder saying that the file/path doesn't exists(error=2), pasting the exact command line in the console works however...

Comment: When you say pasting the command line in the console works, do you just mean that it executes, or that it also solves the problem with the PHP script picking up an incomplete file? Please add your ProcessBuilder code and stack trace to the question.

Comment: It executes and so far, it also solved the problem with php. I'll add a bit more context on the question.

Comment: Are you sure the Java code finishes writing the file (and calls close()) before you try to move it?

Comment: I'm assuming so yes. I'm using [FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)